# Can somebody help me with this forward declaration in C?

Tags: c, declaration, forward

```
typedef void* (*_add_elem)(shm_ds_t *ds, void *key, void *value, int size);
typedef void* (*_lookup)(shm_ds_t *ds, void *key);
typedef void  (*_dump)(shm_ds_t *ds);
typedef int   (*_compare)(void *key1, void *key2);

typedef struct shm_ds{
           void *ds;
           _add_elem shm_add_elem;
           _lookup  shm_lookup;
           _dump dump;
           _compare compare;
} shm_ds_t;
```

Its chicken and egg problem. I have defined some callback fn pointers which uses `shm_ds_t` type, but this type is defined after callback definitions. Similarly, if i change the order, then it reports the same issue with callback definitions which shall be used before defined in this case. Can anyone pls suggest the soln of this ?

Comment: why don't you add `typedef struct shm_ds shm_ds_t`?

Comment: OT: The suffix `_t` is reserved by POSIX. So to stay compatible to POSIX make up a different naming scheme for types.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh, after applying your suggestion i get this compilation error:
note: expected ‘void * (*)(struct shm_ds *, void *, void *, int)’ but argument is of type ‘void * (*)(struct shm_ds_t *, void *, void *, int)’

it is distinguishing between `struct shm_ds` and `struct shm_ds_t`

Comment: It's `shm_ds_t` not `struct shm_ds_t`.

Comment: but compiler is complaining about later.

Comment: the prototype of callbacks becomes `void * (*)(struct shm_ds *, void *, void *, int)`
instead of
void * (*)(shm_ds_t *, void *, void *, int)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the *type* before the callbacks.

Add

```
typedef struct shm_ds shm_ds_t;
```

before the callbacks and later, use

```
struct shm_ds{
           void *ds;
           _add_elem shm_add_elem;
           _lookup  shm_lookup;
           _dump dump;
           _compare compare;
};
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: in other file, i am seeing this error :
shm_ds->shm_add_elem = shm_add_elem; where
shm_add_elem is a pointer to function 
 `void *
shm_ll_add_elem(shm_ds_t *ds, void *key, void *value, int size);`

error :

./LinkedList/./../shm_ds.h:21:1: note: expected ‘void * (*)(struct shm_ds *, void *, void *, int)’ but argument is of type ‘void * (*)(struct shm_ds_t *, void *, void *, int)’

Comment: @AbhishekSagar Show how you call them.

Comment: @AbhishekSagar: "*`but argument is of type ‘void * ()(struct shm_ds_t *, ...`*" again: `struct shm_ds_t ` is *not* a valid type. Use `shm_ds_t`  instead.

Comment: In Main, i am doing the following :
shm_ds->shm_add_elem = shm_add_elem;

where `shm_add_elem` is a pointer to the function `void *
shm_ll_add_elem(shm_ds_t *ds, void *key, void *value, int size)`.